# Data Explorer: ImportError No module named Kqlmagic

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-explorer, azure-notebooks

I'm following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kqlmagic

I have a Databricks cluster so I decided to use the notebook that is available on there.

When I get to step 2 and run:

```
reload_ext Kqlmagic
```

I get the error message:

```
ImportError: No module named Kqlmagic
```

Answer (score 1):

Kqlmagic doesn't work with Databricks notebook. It might be supported in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

Please try running instead of Steps 1,2:

%load_ext Kqlmagic

Comment: Tried that , same result